# Why does Sublime Text editor give an "invalid syntax" error for this valid Python code?

Tags: python, sublimetext3

```
nos=list(map(int,input().split()))
print(nos)
```

This code prints the list correctly in anaconda IDE but the Sublime Text editor gives "invalid syntax" as the error!

Comment: The syntax of the code you provided in the question is correct. Sublime text editor 'invalid syntax' must be flagging something else.

Comment: Which line? When does the error occur: before you input something, or after you entered something? Please be clearer.

Comment: Did you check the python version that is being used in Sublime? Have you installed some compiler plugins to run your code in sublime or it is taking the path from your locally installed python directory?

Comment: Note that it's not Sublime that gives this error, it's the Python interpreter you've told Sublime to run in order to execute your code.

Comment: import sys
print(sys.version)
Ran this to find that I was running python 2.7.16.So I created first installed python 3.8 and then created a new build system for python 3.Ran the code again in the REPL window, after providing in the input(1 2 3) :-      1 2 3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "l.py", line 1, in <module>
    nos = list(map(int, input().split()))
  File "<string>", line 1
    1 2 3
      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

***Repl Closed***

Answer (score 0):

Sublime is probably using python2 and anaconda ide uses python3. In python2 you need to use `raw_input` instead of `input`. `input` function in python2 is equivalent to `eval(input())` in python3, so the input string is interpreted as python code, that's why you're getting syntax error.

Comment: using only the input() to get a single input works perfectly fine.But the problem is with taking multiple inputs in a single line...raw_input() works well in python2 and ran this code successfully.I created a build system for python3 but failed to run this code successfully in it using input() function.

Answer (score 0):

## With Python3

```py
ex = list(map(int, input().split()))
# input: 1 34 56
print(ex)
# prints [1, 34, 56]
```

## With Python2

```py
ex = list(map(int, input().split()))
# input: 1 34 56
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdint>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 1
    1 34 56
       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

## Solution

```py
import sys

if sys.version_info[0] == 2:
    # Make input python2 and python3 compatible
    input = raw_input

# Works everywhere
nos=list(map(int,input().split()))
print(nos)
```